# How to replace a subtree in python

Tags: python, tree

I have my tree data structure as below:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data       = data
        self.children   = []
    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)
```

Then I created a method to accomplish it.

```
def replace(node, newNode):
    if node.data == 1:
        node = newNode
        return
    else:
        for i in xrange(0, len(node.children)):
            replace(node.children[i], newNode)
```

This method is called just like that:

```
replace(mytree,newNode)
```

Since it is recursive call, I think the object get destroyed and the assignment does not happen.

I tried it manually as:

```
mytree.children[0].children[0] = newNode
```

then the tree is correctly updated. How can I achieve it using my method above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment `node = newNode` doesn't do what you want. It doesn't replace the object you know as `node` with `newNode` everywhere. It just rebinds the local variable name `node` to point to the same object as the other local name `newNode`. Other references to the first node (such as in its parent's `children` list) will be unchanged.

To actually do what you want requires more subtlety. The best approach is often often not to replace the node at all, but rather to replace its contents. That is, set `node.data` and `node.children` to be equal to `newNode.data` and `newNode.children` and leave `node` in place. This only fails to work properly if there are other references to `node` or `newNode` and you want them to work properly after the replacement.

The alternative is to do the replacement in the parent of the node you're looking for. This won't work at the top of your tree, so you'll need special logic to handle that situation.

```
def replace(node, newNode):
    if node.value == 1:
        raise ValueError("can't replace the current node this way")

    for index, child in enumerate(node.children):
        if child.data == 1:
            node.children[index] = newNode
            return True

        if replace(child, newNode):
            return True

    return False
```

I've also added some extra logic to stop the recursive processing of the tree when the appropriate node has been found. The function will return `True` if a replacement has been made, or `False` if the right `data` value was not found.

Comment: I am guaranteed to replace only a part of the tree. Do we need the  condition `if node.value == 1`?

Comment: I took that condition from your code. It tells you which node to replace. If you want to replace some other node, change that condition (perhaps pass in a `data` value?).

Comment: Ok I got it. This answer definitely solves my problem :)